# Javascript Pop Up

Tags: javascript, popup

I am looking to have an HTML site with images. I want to click the image and have a pop up window open with an external JS player (I have the JS Source code from an external site). I don't want the link to leave the HTML site but rather pop up and have an X in the corner to return to the site.  Any help would be great.

- Nick

Comment: Any help ? Read the [ask] section.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `<frame>` element, to embed a new document or include the content in a div, that you can `div.style.display = 'none'` with JS

Comment: Thank you! Does that go withing the Img Src line?